# RXJS: Capture drag events not working after first drag

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs6

I have this piece of code where I am trying to capture all the drag events. This code works only for the first drag and stop will not work for successive drags.

Is it because takeUntil cancelling the outer observable? How can I make the code work.

```
const { Observable, fromEvent } = rxjs;
const { takeUntil, switchMap } = rxjs.operators;

const mouseups = fromEvent(document.querySelector('.container'), 
'mouseup'); 
const mousedowns = fromEvent(document.querySelector('.container'), 
'mousedown');
const mousemoves = fromEvent(document.querySelector('.container'), 
'mousemove');

const source = mousedowns.pipe(
  switchMap(e => mousemoves),
  takeUntil(mouseups)
);

source.subscribe(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `takeUntil` inside the `switchMap`, like this:

```
const source = mousedowns.pipe(
  switchMap(e => mousemoves.pipe(
    takeUntil(mouseups)
  ))
);
```

With the `takeUntil` placed inside, the composed observable will unsubscribe from the `mousemoves` observable upon a `mouseup` event, but will remain subscribed to the `mousedown` observable.

Placed outside, it will unsubscribe from the `mousedown` observable upon a `mouseup` event - which is why it stops responding after the first drag.